# How can I get elastic beanstalk to allow large files to be uploaded?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I saw this https://kroltech.com/2014/09/14/quick-tip-increase-upload-size-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-node-js-env/

and created a file called `.ebextensions/00_reload_nginx.conf` with:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 100M;
```

However, when I `ssh` into the machine, that file doesn't exist and nor doe the content. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So stupid! The filename has to end in `.config`, not `.conf`. I hope someone else is saved the hours of agony that I went through.

Comment: Really appreciate you posting an answer as opposed to just removing the question. Saved me quite some time I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all .ebextensions method of adding implementation level configuration and it didn't help me in the latest Amazon Linux AMI. You need to follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#awsui-expandable-section-69-trigger) structure to increase the upload size. 
You need to follow this structure to increase the upload size limit.

Add the below folder setup in the root level of your project folder.

Folder structure (.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf)

```
.platform/
         nginx/
              conf.d/
                    proxy.conf
```

Add this line to proxy.conf (Inside .platform/nginx/conf.d/ folder)

client_max_body_size 50M;

commit this file and deploy again using `eb deploy`.

Comment: this worked for me as well.